# Storing file path and mapping

Tags: c#

I am new to C# so what I want is to map the file path and compare it with

```
"./non-XFA.pdf" and "./XFA.pdf"
```

So, this is what I wrote

```
string[] testFiles = {"./non-XFA.pdf", "./XFA.pdf"};
```

I was thinking to write a foreach loop for this but I could not get any further. Please help

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileName = dialog.FileName.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get each element with `foreach` loop;

```
string[] testFiles = { "./non-XFA.pdf", "./XFA.pdf" };

foreach(string s in testFiles)
{
   Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `Comparer` [Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.comparer.aspx)

```
String str1 = "./non-XFA.pdf";
String str2 = "./XFA.pdf";
Console.WriteLine( "   Invariant Comparer: {0}", Comparer.DefaultInvariant.Compare( str1, str2 ) );
```

hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you don't need to write the path with a ./ in front Linux style if the file path you want is directly in the output folder (like bin\debug).

Secondly, the OpenFileDialog will give you back the filename with extension. If you want to safely extract the Filename and/or extension separately you can use dedicated methods from System.IO.Path to do so.

Answer (score 0):

The `fileName` that you obtained contains the full file path.

1- Get the just the file name from the returned string:

```
string myFile = Path.GetFileName(fileName);
```

2- Now you can compare

```
if(testFiles.Contain(myFile))
{
    //do your checking
}
```